# Nginx location / does not match if the folder exists and the last / is missing.

Tags: nginx

I have the following configuration:

```
# HTTPS server


 server {


    listen 9080;
    server_name  test.test;

    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    access_log logs/test.access.log;
    error_log  logs/test.error.log;


    location  / {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8888/test/beta/;
    }
```

Let's say that there is a folder called test, inside the /test/beta folder. It works if I try to see the test.test/test/ , but it doesn't if I try to see the test.test/test. If the last / is missing, I don't get redirected to :8888, it seems that it doesn't match the rule. The weirdest part of the story is that if I try a folder that does not exist without a / in the end, like http://test.test/not_exists, it gets redirected and I get a 404 error. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This config proxies everything to `localhost:8888`. Look for error in that server.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't proxy on the error that I descripe. I don't leave the 9080 port..

Comment: Is it complete config?